# How to change the size of plot with equal aspect ratio?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems that I can't have both setting equal axes scales AND setting the size of the plot. What I'm doing is:

```
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

If I remove the `figsize` the plot seems to have equal scales, but with `figsize` I have a bigger plot but the scales aren't equal anymore.

Edit: The graph does not necessarily have to be square, just bigger.. please assume that I don't now the exact ratio of the axes

Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the data limits to make the axes square, add `datalim` to your call to `set_aspect`:

```
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

If you want the scaling to change so that the limits are different but the axes look square, you can calculate the axis size ratio and set it explicitly:

```
ax.set_aspect(1./ax.get_data_ratio())
```

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,1000)
y = np.sin(3*x)**2
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.show()
```

[image]

or

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x = np.linspace(0,np.pi,1000)
y = np.sin(3*x)**2
ax.plot(x,y)
ax.set_aspect(1./ax.get_data_ratio())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer does work, although I didn't mean to enforce a square graph (the numbers inside figsize were just for the example, it could as well be (10,20) or whatever..). Actually I'd rather not have it square, I just want it bigger. Is there a way to do it? thanks